# arc USAGE EXCEPTION Choose a workflow

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, phabricator

I have installed arc using below link.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist/

Now when I typing `arc` in the command line it gives me an error

`USAGE EXCEPTION  Choose a workflow!`

So I tried to choose a workflow `arc anoid` but it started that brick game.

.arcconfig looks like below

```
{
  "phabricator.uri": "https://our.phabricator.uri/",
  "history.immutable": true
}
```

How do I start arc?

I am using Mac Catalina 15.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but just in case someone else faces this problem, try running `arc branches`, ideally on the first run it should prompt you to install certificate and so forth.